# How to automatically evaluate expressions after hash rockets in Sublime Text

Tags: ruby, sublimetext, text-editor, expression-evaluation, hashrocket

In [the Ruby Kickstart tutorial](https://vimeo.com/channels/844657) ('05:10), when a hash rocket `# =>` is typed within the text editor, it shows what the expression will evaluate to. For example:

```
2 + 3    # =>    5
```

I am using Sublime Text 2, though cannot find how to get this to work. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: That is just a comment. They start with `#` in Ruby.

Comment: Thats' a comment; as you can see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_comments.htm) comments can start at any position of a line.

Comment: In simplest term it means `2+3` will return `5`. `# =>` is not a method or anything like that. `#` is for comment and `=>` points to return value.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/472413 .

Comment: squiguy, mdesantis, shivam, your comments are all useless. This question is not about Ruby's feature or a method. It is about a feature of a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Ruby Markers](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Ruby%20Markers) plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much - I've got it working now and it's a very useful function.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Cheek's [Seeing is believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/sublime-text-2-and-3-seeing-is-believing) does that.